# Access Hive tables and dump the query to txt file

Tags: bash, hive

I am trying to access hive table and dump the result back into text file. And when I try to do this, I always get the permission denied? Is there something I am missing?

```
bash-3.00$ 'select * from ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME LIMIT 10' > test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
```

And what permission I need in this case? Or my query is wrong?

Comment: can you try "INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/local_out' select * from ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME LIMIT 10"? (if it works then maybe you use a user that doesn't have permissions to the HDFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly — you're missing a `hive -e`. With what you have now, Bash will look for a program named `select * from ATTRIBUTE_DATA_REALTIME LIMIT 10`!

But as for the permissions issue, there are two possibilities:

- If `test.txt` already exists, then you need to run your command as a user that has permission to write to the file. (Use `ls -l test.txt` to see who owns the file and what the permissions on it are.)
- If `test.txt` *doesn't* already exist, then you need to run your command as a user that has permission to write to the directory *containing* the file, i.e., the current directory. (Use `ls -ld .` to see who owns the directory and what the permissions on it are.)

Comment: text.txt file doesn't exists. So I use the command (ls -ld) you gave me. I got this message- `bash-3.00$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x   2 bin      bin          122 Jun  1 19:40 .
`

Comment: @RaihanJamal: Then your command is trying to create a file in a directory owned by `bin` that is *not* group-writeable and *not* world-writeable, and you're running the command as a user who is *not* `bin` and is *not* `root`. You'll need to change one of those things: either run your command as the user who owns the directory, or change who owns the directory, or change the permissions, or run in a different directory, or whatnot. See http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html for a brief tutorial on Unix file-permissions.